# Error in VNC server while taking the GUI session of an ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, vnc-server

I have installed the Tiger VNC server on an ec2 instance. But when I try to connect to the VNC viewer than I get an error:

Unable to connect to the socket: Connection time out (10060)

I have enabled the port 5900 in the security group.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

VNC Server in:

— User Mode is assigned port 5900 for connections and port 5800 for download requests.

— The first instance of VNC Server in Virtual Mode is assigned port 5901 for connections and port 5801 for download requests. Subsequent instances of VNC Server in Virtual Mode are assigned port numbers incremented by one, where possible, for example 5902, 5903 (and 5802, 5803), and so on.

So you need to open the security group rules for taking the GUi session using VNC viewer.